# What do you suggest for insert 120 field in database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, radio-button

I have a web form Where 120 radio-buttons, Each have 2 options (Yes , No)

I want to add selected item of radio buttons to Database.

But insert the 120 field is difficult and if convert to string,  I want to get report 120 fields Separate.

What do you suggest ?

Comment: Why is it difficult? 120 columns of data is no more difficult than a single column, it just makes for a longer statement. That seems a ridiculous amount of options for a single form but whatever. Stick the data into 120 bit columns and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

You will have 120 radio buttons on a single HTML form?  You'll submit them in a single form POST to the server?  That's one busy web form.  Are you sure this is usable?

You have at least two choices:

1. Bind each individual radio button id/value pair to a single session and have a one-to-many relationship between session id parent and radio button child tables.
2. Serialize all those values into a single JSON object and store the CLOB in a relational database or a document in a NoSQL database with the session id as the key.